# Laravel use same form for create and edit

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Am quite new to Laravel and I have to create a form for create and a form for edit. In my form I have quite some jquery ajax posts. Am wondering whether Laravel does provide for an easy way for me to use the same form for my edit and create without having to add tons of logic in my code. I don't want to check if am in edit or create mode every time when assigning values to fields when the form loads. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this with minimum coding?

Comment: I wouldn't go that way, separate responsabilities and setup form and controller methods for creation and edition. Laravel offers nice and easy ways to populate the form fields for you

Comment: Check out the documentation about using [Forms and HTML][http://laravel.com/docs/html], especially the "Opening a new model form"

Comment: Additionally, check out this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510355/define-default-values-for-laravel-form-fields

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I like to use form `model binding` so I can easily populate a form's fields with corresponding value, so I follow this approach (using a `user` model for example):

```php
@if(isset($user))
    {{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['updateroute', $user->id], 'method' => 'patch']) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'createroute']) }}
@endif

    {{ Form::text('fieldname1', Input::old('fieldname1')) }}
    {{ Form::text('fieldname2', Input::old('fieldname2')) }}
    {{-- More fields... --}}
    {{ Form::submit('Save', ['name' => 'submit']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So, for example, from a controller, I basically use the same form for creating and updating, like:

```php
// To create a new user
public function create()
{
    // Load user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
    return View::make('user.createOrUpdate');
}

// To update an existing user (load to edit)
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    // Load user/createOrUpdate.blade.php view
    return View::make('user.createOrUpdate')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**Update**:

`Form` is no longer available (since laravel 5), it's not part of the laravel core.

Comment: This is a nice way to do more while writing less and most of the admin controllers of mine uses this approach with `resource/Restful` controllers:-)

Comment: You can also take an approach of splitting the form up into partials - smaller views of the complete form or parts of the form. You can then have two wrappers - one for creation and one for updating, and each can pull in the form partials they need. Depending how complex your use-case is, and whether the creation vs update forms should be *absolutely identical* or not to end users, this may be more manageable then squeezing it all into one view with multiple conditional sections.

Comment: It's no longer part of Laravel core.

Comment: @Lee, I'm aware of it. Check the date of this answer. It was answered long ago and was valid so...

Comment: I struggled a bit with this solution, as I am a beginner and the solution do not clearly state that I've to define createroute/updateroute in routes/web.php

Comment: @Lee This still works if you use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html , except for that you need to remove Input::old('fieldname1')) part.

Answer (score 29):

Pretty easy in your controller you do:

```php
public function create()
{
    $user = new User;

    $action = URL::route('user.store');

    return View::('viewname')->with(compact('user', 'action'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $action = URL::route('user.update', ['id' => $id]);

    return View::('viewname')->with(compact('user', 'action'));
}
```

And you just have to use this way:

```php
{{ Form::model($user, ['action' => $action]) }}

   {{ Form::input('email') }}
   {{ Form::input('first_name') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Just if you can help, what does the second part of your code, where its doing Form::model, Form::input and Form::close() do?

Comment: How do you deal for using POST or PATCH method depending on create or update ?

Comment: form:model will not work since you are not using PATCH or PUT!

Comment: How can it be replaced with patch?

Comment: I had a problem with this code, it took me several minutes to find out I should use 'url' instead of 'action'.
Like this:
{{ Form::model($user, ['url' => $action]) }}
Hope this help others.

Answer (score 25):

For the creation add an empty object to the view.

```
return view('admin.profiles.create', ['profile' => new Profile()]);
```

Old function has a second parameter, default value, if you pass there the object's field, the input can be reused.

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="name" value="{{old('name', $profile->name)}}">
```

For the form action, you can use the correct endpoint.

```
<form action="{{ $profile->id == null ? '/admin/profiles' :  '/admin/profiles/' . $profile->id }} " method="POST">
```

And for the update you have to use PATCH method.

```
@isset($profile->id)
 {{ method_field('PATCH')}}
@endisset
```

Comment: Instead of `$profile->id` you can use `$profile->exists`, in that way is Model agnostic ;)

Comment: This should be the right answer. For those who don't (want to) use the LaravelCollective Form package. If you really work with web designers, we should stick to pure html in blade views as much as humanly possible. Isn't that the whole point of VMC? Only, take care of the post versus patch method.

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct way. Use ->exists as suggested.  Form library imposes too much layout to be generically useful.  Sooner or later you realise that you cannot get it to do what you want and have forgotten how to write simple html form inputs. http://novate.co.uk/reusing-form-in-laravel-for-both-create-and-update/

Comment: Another tip is if the action url depends on logic you can pass it's value in from the controller. It takes that logic out of the view so it's a little cleaner.

Comment: is there a better way to handle children objects? currently I have `old('stat_file_date', !empty($data_request->enrollment_data->stat_file_date) ? $data_request->enrollment_data->stat_file_date : null)` which works, but is really cumbersome... the problem is when attempting to create new objects, there aren't any children so it can't get the value and throws an exception "Trying to get property 'stat_file_date' of non-object"

Answer (score 15):

Another clean method with a small controller, two views and a partial view :

**UsersController.php**

```
public function create()
{
    return View::('create');
}    

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return View::('edit')->with(compact('user'));
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'route' => ['users.index'], 'role' => 'form' ) ) }}
    @include('_fields')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::model( $user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'put', 'role' => 'form'] ) }}
    @include('_fields')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**_fields.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::text('fieldname1') }}
{{ Form::text('fieldname2') }}
{{ Form::button('Save', ['type' => 'submit']) }}
```

Comment: How do you handle prepopulating the form fields with either saved content (if editing) or submitted content (if validation fails)?

Comment: It's automatic. On create/update failed : repopulating is done with Input array. On get /edit : data are taken from model thanks to Form::model()

Comment: I think this is actually the cleanest/best answer given.

Comment: But how do you actually save all of the edited fields to the object? All I see you doing in your example is in the controller you are finding the object and then creating the new view? What about where you actually save the edits? @SamuelDeBacker

Comment: @Max the edits are saved on the update Method. Something like `$return = DB::transaction(function($id) use ($id) { $input = Input::all(); $user = User::find($id); $user->name = $input['name']; return $user->save(); });` then you can `if($return){ return Redirect::to('user'); } else { return Redirect::back()->withInput(); }`

Comment: I like this answer because your edit and create will have different headings etc. Only the fields need to be in a separate file.

Answer (score 4):

Simple and clean :)

**UserController.php**

```
public function create() {
    $user = new User();

    return View::make('user.edit', compact('user'));
}

public function edit($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);

    return View::make('user.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['url' => ['/user', $user->id]]) }}
   {{ Form::text('name') }}
   <button>save</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Clean code. But what if user cancels the sign up or refreshes the sign up page several times or restarts the browser(ie, destroying the session)? There will be lots of vague/incomplete entries in the table

Comment: $user = new User(); - it doesnt execute sql query.

 New entry is added into sql only in your UPDATE or STORE method.

Answer (score 3):

For example, your controller, retrive data and put the view

```
class ClassExampleController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {   

        $test = Test::first(1);

        return view('view-form',[
            'field' => $test,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Add default value in the same form, create and edit, is very simple

```
<!-- view-form file -->
<form action="{{ 
    isset($field) ? 
    @route('field.updated', $field->id) : 
    @route('field.store')
}}">
    <!-- Input case -->
    <input name="name_input" class="form-control" 
    value="{{ isset($field->name) ? $field->name : '' }}">
</form>
```

And, you remember add csrf_field, in case a POST method requesting. Therefore, repeat input, and select element, compare each option

```
<select name="x_select">
@foreach($field as $subfield)

    @if ($subfield == $field->name)
        <option val="i" checked>
    @else
        <option val="i" >
    @endif

@endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating two methods - one for creating new row and one for updating, you should use `findOrNew()` method. So:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id = 0)
{
    $user = User::findOrNew($id);
    $user->fill($request->all());
    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Article is a model containing two fields - title and content 
    Create a view as pages/add-update-article.blade.php   

        @if(!isset($article->id))
            <form method = "post" action="add-new-article-record">
            @else
             <form method = "post" action="update-article-record">
            @endif
                {{ csrf_field() }} 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>            
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title" name="title" value={{$article->title}}>
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="content" name="content">
                    {{$article->content}}

                    </textarea>
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('content') }}</span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{{ $article->id }}}"> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>

Route(web.php): Create routes to controller 

        Route::get('/add-new-article', 'ArticlesController@new_article_form');
        Route::post('/add-new-article-record', 'ArticlesController@add_new_article');
        Route::get('/edit-article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@edit_article_form');
        Route::post('/update-article-record', 'ArticlesController@update_article_record');

Create ArticleController.php
       public function new_article_form(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Articles();
        return view('pages/add-update-article', $article)->with('article', $article);
    }

    public function add_new_article(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', 'content' => 'required']);
        Articles::create($request->all());
        return redirect('articles');
    }

    public function edit_article_form($id)
    {
        $article = Articles::find($id);
        return view('pages/add-update-article', $article)->with('article', $article);
    }

    public function update_article_record(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', 'content' => 'required']);
        $article = Articles::find($request->id);
        $article->title = $request->title;
        $article->content = $request->content;
        $article->save();
        return redirect('articles');
    }
```

Comment: You could do with adding some text to this to explain how it relates to the original Q.

Answer (score 1):

You can use form binding and 3 methods in your `Controller`. Here's what I do

```
class ActivitiesController extends BaseController {
    public function getAdd() {
        return $this->form();
    }
    public function getEdit($id) {
        return $this->form($id);
    }
    protected function form($id = null) {
        $activity = ! is_null($id) ? Activity::findOrFail($id) : new Activity;

        //
        // Your logic here
        //

        $form = View::make('path.to.form')
            ->with('activity', $activity);

        return $form->render(); 
    }
}
```

And in my views I have

```
{{ Form::model($activity, array('url' => "/admin/activities/form/{$activity->id}", 'method' => 'post')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, it has form_for helper, so we could make a function like form_for.

We can make a Form macro, for example in resource/macro/html.php:

(if you don't know how to setup a macro, you can google "laravel 5 Macro")

```
Form::macro('start', function($record, $resource, $options = array()){
    if ((null === $record || !$record->exists()) ? 1 : 0) {
        $options['route'] = $resource .'.store';
        $options['method'] = 'POST';
        $str = Form::open($options);
    } else {
        $options['route'] = [$resource .'.update', $record->id];
        $options['method'] = 'PUT';
        $str = Form::model($record, $options);
    }
    return $str;
});
```

The Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $category = null;
    return view('admin.category.create', compact('category'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $category = Category.find($id);
    return view('admin.category.edit', compact('category'));
}
```

Then in the view _form.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::start($category, 'admin.categories', ['class' => 'definewidth m20']) !!}
// here the Form fields
{{!! Form::close() !!}}
```

Then view create.blade.php:

```
@include '_form'
```

Then view edit.blade.php:

```
@include '_form'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple way to create or edit record using same form .
I have created form.blade.php file for create and edit

```
 @extends('layouts.admin')
    @section('content')
       <div class="card shadow mb-4">
           <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
               <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Create User</h6>
           </div>
           <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" action="{{isset($user)? route('users.update',$user->id):route('users.store')}}">
                @csrf
                @if (isset($user))
                    @method('PUT')
                @endif
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{isset($user->name) ? $user->name: old('name')}}" type="text" name="name" required>
                        @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Email address</label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{isset($user->email) ? $user->email:old('email')}}"  type="email" name="email" required>
                        @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"  value="{{old('password')}}" type="text" name="password" required>
                        @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-icon-split">
                        <span class="text">Save</span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="{{route('users.index')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-icon-split">
                        <span class="text">Cancel</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
           </div>
       </div>
    @endsection
```

And in my controller

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.user.form');
    }

public function edit($id){
    $user= User::find($id);
    return view('admin.user.form', compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserController.php

```
use View;

public function create()
{
    return View::make('user.manage', compact('user'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return View::make('user.manage', compact('user'));
}
```

user.blade.php

```
@if(isset($user))
    {{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'user.store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}
@endif

// fields

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you!!

`form.blade.php`

```
@php
$name         = $user->name ?? null;
$email        = $user->email ?? null;
$info         = $user->info ?? null;
$role         = $user->role ?? null;
@endphp

<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', $name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', $email, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('role', 'Função') !!}
        {!! Form::text('role', $role, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('info', 'Informações') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('info', $info, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<a class="btn btn-danger float-right" href="{{ route('users.index') }}">CANCELAR</a>
```

`create.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Criar usuário')

@section('content')
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'UsersController@store', 'method' => 'POST'])  !!}
            @include('users.form')
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('password', 'Senha') !!}
                {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('password', 'Confirmação de senha') !!}
                {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::submit('ADICIONAR', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

`edit.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Editar usuário')

@section('content')
        {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
            @include('users.form', compact('user'))
            {!! Form::submit('EDITAR', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        <a href="{{route('users.editPassword', $user->id)}}">Editar senha</a>
@endsection
```

`UsersController.php`

```
use App\User;

Class UsersController extends Controller {
  #... 
    public function create()
    {
        return view('users.create';
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user  = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('users.edit', compact('user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **any** in the route

```
Route::any('cr', [CreateContent::class, 'create_content'])
->name('create_resource');
```

in controller use

```
User::UpdateOrCreate([id=>$user->id], ['field_name'=>value, ...]);
```