# How to get requests in update method in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update the edited data using auto generated `update` method in the controller. I edited the data by following process ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844022/laravel-use-same-form-for-create-and-edit?answertab=active#tab-top))

**Controller :**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = Usermd::find($id);
    return View::make('editcreate', compact('user'));
}
```

**Route :**

```
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'CreateUser@edit');
```

**View :**

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['url' => ['/user/update', $user->id]]) }}
   {{ Form::text('u_name',$user->u_name ) }}
   {!! Form::input('submit', 'Update User') !!}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Above code is working fine for me, now i wanted to update the records.

**Route :**

```
Route::get('/user/update/{id}', 'CreateUser@update');
```

**Controller :**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        echo $request->u_name;
        echo $id;
    }
```

When i `echo` the request object in update method it does not showing anything and also returning the error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Can anyone guide me where i'm wrong that i can fix this issue. Also i wanted to know the edit process is correct or i should search some better. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You.

Comment: I think you should set Route post not get

Comment: @rad11 yes I did and now its working. Thanks for sharing knowledge

Comment: If you want you can name your route the same (i.e: /user/edit/{id}) as soon as their method (POST, GET, ...) is different

Comment: Route::any('/user/update/{id}', 'CreateUser@update');  try it

Answer (score 0):

Default update is not using GET method, you should define you route by this:

```
Route::PUT('/user/update/{id}', 'CreateUser@update');
```