# how to use same form for edit and create using isset to the value field in the form and how to customise this routes for update and store?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

This is my first form for create.

```
create form //
    <form action="{{route('surplus.genrate')}}" method="POST" id="offer_letter_gen" >
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
    </form>
```

This is code for edit

```
edit //
 <form action="{{route('surplus.edit')}}" method="POST" id="offer_letter_gen" >
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
    </form>
```

how i can use the same form in create and update with manageable routes 
for them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel use same form for create and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844022/laravel-use-same-form-for-create-and-edit)

Comment: how will mange the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar on this week. I have a modal with a form like yours:

```
    <form action="{{route('surplus.genrate')}}" method="POST" id="offer_letter_gen" >
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
       <input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "
         placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
    </form>
```

I added a javascript function to change the url of the form depending if it's an edit or a create.

**Javascript function:**

```
function updateurl(id, url){ //Where id is the form id and url is the url for create or for edit
  $('#'+id).prop('action',url);
}
```

**Then in a button or something:**

```
//For creating
onclick="updateurl('offer_letter_gen','{{route('surplus.genrate')}}')"
//For editing
onclick="updateurl('offer_letter_gen','{{route('surplus.edit')}}')"
```

I think this was what you were trying to achieve

Comment: you can leave the action as is, the javascript code will change it on the go ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really know how do you want to edit something without the ID, but you can do something like this form:

```
<form action="{{route('surplus.genrate')}}" method="POST" id="offer_letter_gen" >
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="your possile ID" value='{{ $id_of_record_to_edit ?? '' }}' />
<input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
<input type="email" class="form-control m-input result "placeholder="" name="recurring_total" id="tot_extra" readonly>
```

If you have an ID of the record, you can simply update by id... If not, use updateOrCreate. In you controller, you can do what the docs tell us to do...
Check -> [updateOrCreate() documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

```
public function saveOrUpdate(Request $request)
{
handle it...
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('page..', 'ControllerNameController@saveOrUpdate)->name('save_or_update');
```

Hope it helped.